# ember js this.set() breaking bootstrap plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

on didInsertElement i have initialised bootstrap popover and it works fine until i run an action i.e submit a form, after i save the form data on db i make a request to get the current saved data from api and then i use this.set() to update the model in realtime for the user... however after i use this.set() the popover breaks... to explain it a little better i'm gonna use an example below:

```
<form {{action 'saveForm' on='submit'}}>
   {{input type="text" value=firstName class="form-control" placeholder="Firstname"}}
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Submit</button>
</form>

{{#each firstname in model.firstNames}}
  <span data-toggle="popover" data-title="Firstname" data-content="{{unbound firstname}}" data-placement="top">Firstname</span>
{{/each}}
```

after using this.set() the popover inside #each doesn't work anymore..

**UPDATE:** this is the action where i call this.set()

```
App.firstNamesController = App.AppController.extend({
    actions: {
        updateFirstnames: function () {
            $.getJSON('/api/firstnames/get/', function (jsonResponse) {
                this.set('firstNames', jsonResponse.data.firstNames);
            }.bind(this));
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE #2:**

```
App.firstNamesView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'firstNamesTemplate',
    didInsertElement: function() {
        $('span[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
            trigger: 'click'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Please share the code where you are calling this.set

Comment: @Gaurav i just posted the code.. thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to re-initialize the eventListeners as you did in didInsertElement after you set the new data?

Comment: @Jeff no i didn't, can you pls explain how to do it? thanks!

Comment: sorry, I cant really, I just a similar situation with a datepickerplugin. After reading the docs again I coulnt find a better event than `didInsertElement` to bind the eventListeners for the popover. Could you share that `didInsertElement`?

Comment: @Jeff on Update #2 u find the didInsertElement code, this works until 
`this.set('firstNames', jsonResponse.data.firstNames)` is run.. then it breaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to (as Jeff mentioned) re-initialize your listeners after you set new names. `didInsertElement` isn't going to run every time new elements enter the DOM, it's just going to run when the view has been inserted for the first time once it's elements are ready.

Re-setting `firstNames` is adding new elements to the DOM after you set your listeners, so they aren't going to have the listeners set on them.

Untested solution:

```
App.firstNamesController = App.AppController.extend({
  actions: {
    updateFirstnames: function() {
      $.getJSON('/api/firstnames/get/', function(jsonResponse) {
        this.set('firstNames', jsonResponse.data.firstNames);

        // add this after setting names:
        Ember.run.next(this, function () {
          $('span[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        });
      }.bind(this));
    }
  }
});
```

Also, your selector in your jQuery is targeting `span[data-toggle="tooltip"]` but your template has `span[data-toggle="popover"]` - is that a typo?

**EDIT 1**

Another option could be to observe the `model.firstNames` property and have the listeners get set any time `model.firstNames` changes. But observers can be a pain to manage.

```
// in your controller:
toolTipObserver: function () {
  Ember.run.next(this, function () {
    $('span[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });
}.observes('model.firstNames')
```